# Cassandra Time Window Compaction Strategy

Tags: cassandra

There is Cassandra table:

```
CREATE TABLE data.data (
dataid bigint,
sequencenumber bigint,
createdat timestamp,
datetime timestamp,
PRIMARY KEY (dataid, sequencenumber)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (sequencenumber ASC)
AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
AND comment = ''
AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.TimeWindowCompactionStrategy', 'compaction_window_size': '7', 'compaction_window_unit': 'DAYS', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
AND default_time_to_live = 0
AND gc_grace_seconds = 3600
AND max_index_interval = 2048
AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
AND min_index_interval = 128
AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
CREATE INDEX data_datetime_idx ON data.data(datetime);
```

Writing data with write options ttl for 7 days.
What I noticed, every same day of week we hit big Cassandra node load, especially big wa (I/O). I think this is related with compaction strategy. Should I use this strategy with lesser compaction_window_strategy e.g. 3 days? How to tune compaction strategy with ttl? How these params correlates? O maybe I have wrong primary key?

Cassandra ring 3x nodes, 8CPU, 16GB ram. Every node load ~90GiB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your TWCS configuration seems sub-optimal. What you've told Cassandra to do is have a window/bucket (consolidation) occur every 7 days, which is also your TTL. Typically what you want, from what I have read, is 15-30 "buckets" for your TTL period. That being said, what you'd want to do in your case is take 7 days and divide that into, say, 30 buckets. If you changed it to 12 HOUR buckets, you'd have 14 buckets, which seems OK.

For 12 hours, STCS would occur for the current bucket/window. At the 12 hour mark, all of the sstables that existed in that window would be consolidated into a single sstable. After 7 days, you'd have 14 sstables in which the oldest could simply be deleted (v.s. a compaction comparison).

As long as you're not updating or deleting rows that cross windows, TWCS can save a lot of resources and is very efficient. We use it whenever we can. If you're updating rows that exist in a prior bucket, TWCS is not a good choice.

Also remember to turn off repair on the table that has TWCS. I have seen that mess things up quite badly.

As for your big wait I/O issues, it could be compaction, could be flushing, could be many things. With your current TWCS configuration, it could be compaction (depending on how many and how large the sstables are). I think you could try to use other tools to see where the busy threads are (e.g. ttop). Either way, I'd fix your TWCS configuration to be in line with best practices.

-Jim